# Скачанный архив в неверном формате после разархивированияю

Tags: java, zip

если я скачал архив и разархивировал его через код на Java, я столкнулся с проблемой, что мой файл имеет непонятное расширение, но он должен быть в расширении файла или  .fiel (ps у него есть exe, dll файлы и т. д.) код

```
private boolean unpackZip()
    {       

 InputStream is;
 ZipInputStream zis;
 try 
         {
 is = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Альфа/Desktop/majnkraft12.zip");
 zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));          
   ZipEntry ze;

  while((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) 
             {
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buffer = new byte[32784];
     int count;

String filename = ze.getName();
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/1425ad");

 // reading and writing
  while((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) 
                 {
  baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
     byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    fout.write(bytes);             
     baos.reset();
 }  fout.close();               
 zis.closeEntry();
             }

 zis.close();
         } 
   catch(IOException e)
         {
 e.printStackTrace();
  return false;
         }

    return true;
        }
```

Comment: `FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/1425ad"); ` замените на `new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/" + filename)`;

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Desktop\.minecraft (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)

Comment: Видимо нет дирректорий(`C:\Users\Desktop\`). Измените выходной путь папки. Или создайте, которые вам нужны

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\ormen\.minecraft\bin (Системе не удается найти указанный путь) , вот код ( FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:/ormen/"+filename);)

Comment: может я туплю, и не так понял ваш ответ, если это так. то сорян(

Comment: а всё, понял. У вас в архиве не только файлы, но и папки с вложенностями? Воспользуйтесь примерами https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920684/java-extracting-zip-file-with-multiple-subdirectories и https://www.thejavaprogrammer.com/java-zip-unzip-files/

Comment: Огромное тебе спасибо, ты лучший |

Comment: есть хотя бы нормальные люди, которпым непонятно они просят вопрос, а не как ебаные американцы, на удержание вопросы ставят и банят их

Comment: )) Не за что. Удачи!